# select multiple not passing all the selected values

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

path="userRoles" is multi select field. Which is populated with the method "initializeRoles()" from the controller. I have a converter also to convert Roles to UserRoles object. When I submit the form even after selecting all the Roles, I get only the first selected one always to the converter class as shown below. Why I am not getting String[] from JSP?

Output in the Converter class:

1

string

JSP code:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>User Create Form</title>
    <link href="<c:url value='/static/css/bootstrap.css' />" rel="stylesheet"></link>
    <link href="<c:url value='/static/css/app.css' />" rel="stylesheet"></link>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="generic-container">
        <%@include file="authheader.jsp" %>

        <div class="well lead">User Create Form</div>
        <form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="user" class="form-horizontal">
            <form:input type="hidden" path="userid" id="userid"/>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                    <label class="col-md-3 control-lable" for="firstName">First Name</label>
                    <div class="col-md-7">
                        <form:input type="text" path="firstName" id="firstName" class="form-control input-sm"/>
                        <div class="has-error">
                            <form:errors path="firstName" class="help-inline"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                    <label class="col-md-3 control-lable" for="middleName">Middle Name</label>
                    <div class="col-md-7">
                        <form:input type="text" path="middleName" id="middleName" class="form-control input-sm" />
                        <div class="has-error">
                            <form:errors path="middleName" class="help-inline"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                    <label class="col-md-3 control-lable" for="lastName">Last Name</label>
                    <div class="col-md-7">
                        <form:input type="text" path="lastName" id="lastName" class="form-control input-sm" />
                        <div class="has-error">
                            <form:errors path="lastName" class="help-inline"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                    <label class="col-md-3 control-lable" for="username">Username</label>
                    <div class="col-md-7">
                        <c:choose>
                            <c:when test="${edit}">
                                <form:input type="text" path="username" id="username" class="form-control input-sm" disabled="true"/>
                            </c:when>
                            <c:otherwise>
                                <form:input type="text" path="username" id="username" class="form-control input-sm" />
                                <div class="has-error">
                                    <form:errors path="username" class="help-inline"/>
                                </div>
                            </c:otherwise>
                        </c:choose>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                    <label class="col-md-3 control-lable" for="password">Password</label>
                    <div class="col-md-7">
                        <form:input type="password" path="password" id="password" class="form-control input-sm" />
                        <div class="has-error">
                            <form:errors path="password" class="help-inline"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                    <label class="col-md-3 control-lable" for="email">Email</label>
                    <div class="col-md-7">
                        <form:input type="text" path="email" id="email" class="form-control input-sm" />
                        <div class="has-error">
                            <form:errors path="email" class="help-inline"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                    <label class="col-md-3 control-lable" for="userRoles">Roles</label>
                    <div class="col-md-7">
                        <form:select path="userRoles" items="${roles}" multiple="true" itemValue="roleid" itemLabel="roleName" class="form-control input-sm" />
                        <div class="has-error">
                            <form:errors path="userRoles" class="help-inline"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-actions floatRight">
                    <c:choose>
                        <c:when test="${edit}">
                            <input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"/> or <a href="<c:url value='/list' />">Cancel</a>
                        </c:when>
                        <c:otherwise>
                            <input type="submit" value="Register" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"/> or <a href="<c:url value='/list' />">Cancel</a>
                        </c:otherwise>
                    </c:choose>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form:form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Controller code:

```
package com.rsa.tools.springmvc.web.controller;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.MessageSource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.validation.FieldError;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import com.rsa.tools.springmvc.model.User;
import com.rsa.tools.springmvc.model.UserRoles;
import com.rsa.tools.springmvc.service.UserManagementService;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    UserManagementService umService;

    @Autowired
    MessageSource messageSource;

    @RequestMapping(value="/list", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listUsers(ModelMap model) {
        List<User> users = umService.getAllUsersOrderedByUsername();
        model.addAttribute("users", users);
        return "userslist";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/newuser" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String newUser(ModelMap model) {
        User user = new User();
        model.addAttribute("user", user);
        model.addAttribute("edit", false);
        return "registration";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/newuser" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveUser(@Valid User user, BindingResult result, ModelMap model) {
        System.out.println(user);
        System.out.println(result.getAllErrors());
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "registration";
        }

        if(!umService.isUsernameUnique(user.getUsername())) {
            FieldError usernameError = new FieldError("user","username",messageSource.getMessage("non.unique.username", new String[]{user.getUsername()}, Locale.getDefault()));
            result.addError(usernameError);
            return "registration";
        }

        umService.addUser(user);

        model.addAttribute("success", "User " + user.getFirstName() + " "+ user.getLastName() + " registered successfully");
        //return "success";
        return "registrationsuccess";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/edit-user-{username}" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String editUser(@PathVariable String username, ModelMap model) {
        User user = umService.findByUsername(username);
        model.addAttribute("user", user);
        model.addAttribute("edit", true);
        return "registration";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/edit-user-{username}" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String updateUser(@Valid User user, BindingResult result, ModelMap model, @PathVariable String username) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "registration";
        }

        umService.editUser(user);

        model.addAttribute("success", "User " + user.getFirstName() + " "+ user.getLastName() + " updated successfully");
        return "registrationsuccess";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/delete-user-{username}" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String deleteUser(@PathVariable String username) {
        umService.deleteUser(username);
        return "redirect:/list";
    }

    @ModelAttribute("roles")
    public List<UserRoles> initializeRoles() {
        return umService.getAllUserRoles();
    }
}
```

Converter code:

```
package com.rsa.tools.springmvc.configuration.web.converter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.rsa.tools.springmvc.dao.UserDao;
import com.rsa.tools.springmvc.model.UserRoles;

@Component
public class UserRolesConverter implements Converter<Object, List<UserRoles>> {

    @Autowired
    UserDao userDao;

    @Override
    public List<UserRoles> convert(Object roles) {
        List<UserRoles> userRoles = new ArrayList<UserRoles>();
        System.out.println(roles);
        if (roles instanceof String) {
            System.out.println("string");
            String sRoles = (String)roles;
            UserRoles ur = userDao.findByRoleid(Long.parseLong(sRoles));
            userRoles.add(ur);
        } else if (roles instanceof String[]) {
            System.out.println("string[]");
            for (String role : (String[])roles) {
                UserRoles ur = userDao.findByRoleid(Long.parseLong(role));
                userRoles.add(ur);
            }
        }
        return userRoles;
    }
}
```

Web Configuration:

```
package com.rsa.tools.springmvc.configuration.web;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.MessageSource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource;
import org.springframework.format.FormatterRegistry;
import org.springframework.validation.Validator;
import org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;

import com.rsa.tools.springmvc.configuration.web.converter.UserRolesConverter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.rsa.tools.springmvc.web.controller", "com.rsa.tools.springmvc.configuration.web.converter" })
public class ApplicationWebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    UserRolesConverter userRolesConverter;

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver resolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource source = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        source.setBasename("messages");
        return source;
    }

    @Override
    public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
        registry.addConverter(userRolesConverter);
    }

    @Override
    public Validator getValidator() {
        LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
        validator.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource());
        return validator;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("/static/");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Added one more converter class for String[]. Then I started getting multiple values which were selected in in UI. Why I have to write two Converter classes. Is there a way to combine both the classes.

```
public class UserRolesConverter1 implements Converter<String[], List<UserRoles>> {
...
    @Override
    public List<UserRoles> convert(String[] roles) {
```